# creating different attributes for an array of nodes

Tags: ruby, savon

I am trying to build the following xml via Savon:

```
<host-selection>
    <ip-address-list-selection>
            <ip-address value="1.1.1.1" />
            <ip-address value="2.2.2.2" />
     </ip-address-list-selection>
</host-selection>
```

I was hoping that something like this would work. But the 'value' is not added.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
ip = ['1.1.1.1', '2.2.2.2']
ip_list = {'ip-address-list-selection' => {'ip-address' => []}}
ip.each do |ip_i|
       ip_list['ip-address-list-selection']['ip-address'] << {:attributes! =>{'ip-address' => {'value' => ip_i}}}
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following. It will not result in inline attributes but nested values.

```
ip = ['1.1.1.1', '2.2.2.2']
ip_list = {'ip-address-list-selection' => {'ip-address' => []}}
ip.each do |ip_i|
       ip_list['ip-address-list-selection']['ip-address'] << {'value' => ip_i}
end
```